# Backup of local resources on Azure cloud services

Tags: azure, backup, azure-worker-roles

We have a worker role that's using local storage directory to save files uploaded by the customer and we'd need to have a backup of those files.

Given that we already planned to change the worker role to the storage services available on Azure, is there a temporary solution that we could use immediately to backup those files?

Is there an automated way (even with 3rd party services) to backup a local storage directory or even the entire C disk?

Comment: why don't you mount an Azure Files container and then through automation copy everything to a secondary location  /different region ?

Comment: Could you please provide some references (e.g. documentation, blog posts) for such solution? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AzCopy](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/storage-use-azcopy/) to bulk copy files from a local file system to an Azure blob container.

If you use the /XO option, that will only copy files newer than the last backup - in combination with the /Y option to suppress confirmation prompts, this is handy for running as a scheduled task to keep the blob backup current.